# Way to define others layout() parts such layout()->content?

Tags: zend-framework

Ive done some search but no success.. i am trying to figure out how to define others `layout()` parts such `layout()->content` variable.. i would love to get int `layout()->navigation` (a custom one) which display the navigation..

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by just creating a new variable in layout, you can define it in your controller (preferably in init or postDispatch). Just like this:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->view->layout()->motd = '<b>Message of the day.</b>';
}
```

Then in your actual view where you want to see the message, all you have to do is:

```
<?php echo $this->layout()->motd; ?>
```

If you want something fancier, such as rendering a whole page or sidebar, try the following:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->view->layout()->sidebar = $this->view->action('render', 'sidebar');
}
```

With render being the action (including render.phtml) and sidebar being the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can create additional 'parts' of layout simply by assigning a value to your new part. ZF will take care of the rest. For example, in a bootstrap.php you could do:

```
public function _initNewLayoutPart() {
    $view = $this->bootstrap('view')->getResource('view');
    $view->layout()->newpart = 'some new part';                
}
```

Then in your layout.phtml you could just echo the new part:

```
<?php  echo $this->layout()->newpart; ?>
```